# How to find total salary of all departments

Tags: sql

```
SELECT D_ID, SUM(SALARY) 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY D_ID.
```

I want to get total salary of all departments with this query.

Comment: Please tag DBMS, provide sample data, expected result, remove ALLCAPS.

Comment: Do you mean total salary by departments?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does your query give you the salary sum per department? And you want the one total sum over all departments instead?

Comment: Thorsten Kettner ur right

Comment: any tip or answer??

Answer (score 3):

If department wise sum then your query is proper.

```
SELECT D_ID, SUM(SALARY) 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY D_ID
```

If you want the total sum then can do a `sum` of salary.

```
SELECT SUM(SALARY) 
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

If you want to display both a single query then use:

```
SELECT D_ID, 
       SUM(SALARY) OVER (PARTITION BY D_ID) AS [Dept Salary], 
       SUM(SALARY) OVER () AS [Total Salary] 
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: SIR i want to show sum of  department wise salary and also sum of all department salaries in a single column

Comment: @MYasirLatifKassar single column or single query??

Comment: @MYasirLatifKassar If its single query, I have updated my answer.Please do check and let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ideal query should be as below:

```
SELECT D.D_ID, SUM(E.SALARY) 
FROM DEPARTMENT D
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON D.D_ID=E.D_ID
GROUP BY D.D_ID
UNION 
SELECT 0 D_ID, SUM(SALARY) SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: IR i want to show sum of department wise salary and also sum of all department salaries in a single column – M Yasir Latif Kassar just now

Comment: Updated the query. The query will now show last record as sum of all salaries with 0 value in D_ID column.

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comments, I think he is asking for this.

```
mysql> select * from xyz;
+------+------------+---------------+--------+------------+
| roll | name       | location      | salary | department |
+------+------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|    1 | Pranav     | Parasi        | 25000  | A          |
|    2 | Pragya     | Chitwan       | 20000  | A          |
|    3 | Prabhuddha | New Playmouth | 28000  | B          |
|    4 | Smriti     | Kathmandu     | 35000  | B          |
|    5 | Shruti     | Butwal        | 40000  | A          |
+------+------------+---------------+--------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select department, sum(salary) from xyz group by department;
+------------+-------------+
| department | sum(salary) |
+------------+-------------+
| A          |       85000 |
| B          |       63000 |
+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

By doing this, we can show the department in one column and the department's salary in another column.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks. I did as you said. I didn't notice the GNOME terminal option named "Copy as HTML". So cool and handy. Linux is great.